# Catching partial close in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I've run into a small design problem.

I have a partial where you can fill in some form information, and a second partial where you can select some additional items. I store the details of the first partial in `localstorage` so that it can be filled back in when the user returns from the second partial (it makes sense, don't worry).

However, I want to delete the `localStorage` when the user leaves to any other part of the website, but there are about a dozen ways to do that. I would like to handle this with a `partialClose` event, but I can't seem to get it to work (I'm new at web development so forgive me if this is a stupid question).

What is the proper way of handling a partial close/switch event with both AngularJS and Jquery?

Comment: Why use localStorage instead of your controllers $scope?  Unless you are completely refreshing the page when switching from one form to another, you can keep all of your data within Angular.  This would give you the benefit of binding data from your first form to your second automatically.

Comment: The two forms use different controllers. The second one is used multiple times throughout the site so I would like to keep it generic and separate.

Comment: have you tried directives?

Comment: How can I use directives to store data across 2 specific pages, but not across any others?

Comment: There are lots of ways to share data between controllers.  If the controllers are closely related, you can use a parent scope. The preferred way is to use a service or factory https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Comment: But how do I use that to determine when the user has left the first partial? In my last reply I misrepresented my issue.

I want the user to go from partial1 to partial2. Then when they return to partial1 their form data is intact. But once they leave partial1 to any other partial I want that data deleted so that when they return the page will be blank.

Comment: Is there not an event I can handle for when one partial closes?

Comment: There is! The event is $locationChangeStart

Answer (score 0):

The event for a partial changing is $locationChangeStart